# how to use amazon iOS sdk with IAM credentials for S3 services (read/write photos)?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We implemented IAM on the server side, now I want to use the session token returned from server side to upload/read images to/from amazon s3.

Are there any samples for this kinda similar tasks? All I can find is using cognito credential provider for the S3 on the mobile side.

This is a data structure returned from server side, any suggestions to wrap it in iOS credential provider and do the operations on amazon S3?

```
{
    "Credentials":{
        "AccessKeyId":"...",
        "SecretAccessKey":"...",
        "SessionToken":"...",
        "Expiration":"..."
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser":{
         "AssumedRoleId":"...",
         "Arn":"arn:aws:sts::..."
         }

}
```

Comment: Is this still an issue? Are you using the old (v1) or the new (v2) version of the AWS SDK? In general, on the Android SDK, you can provide a different implementation of the credentials provider classes, passing in the results from the STS call. I'd imagine the iOS SDK has the same capability.

Comment: @Viccari this used to be a question, I am not sure nowadays if it's still a problem